# How can I pass data in real time to my PC running a python script via an Arduino Bluetooth module?

Tags: python, c, bluetooth, arduino

I have a force sensitive resistor(FSR) in my circuit and I would like my Arduino to pass this data to my PC, running a python script, via bluetooth.

Here is the bluetooth shield I am using for this project: [Bluetooth Shield](http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=Bluetooth_Shield_for_Arduino)

I've attempted to mimic the examples on here but neither scenario involved a situation where the Arduino Bluetooth interacts with a PC's bluetooth and the code wouldn't even upload when I used their sketch.

Operating System: Windows 10

Here is the code for my FSR:

```
const int fsrAnalogPin = A0;
int fsrReading;

void setup(void) {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  fsrReading = analogRead(fsrAnalogPin);
  int num = fsrReading/3;
  Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
  Serial.println(num);
  delay(50);
}
```

Here is my code for the Python script(Bluetooth not implemented yet):

```
import serial

serialArduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)

while True:
    while (serialArduino.inWaiting() == 0):
        pass
    valueRead =(serialArduino.readline())
    print(valueRead)
```

What can I change in my FSR code and Python code to send and receive the data via bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you did not initialize a serial connection to your shield.

Depending on Arduino board usied you should select the serial port used by th eshiled.

If youo use Uno yo umust use SoftwareSerial Library to communicate with your code as in this example

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  
#define RxD 7
#define TxD 6
SoftwareSerial BlueToothSerial(RxD,TxD);
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(38400);     
   BlueToothSerial.begin(38400); 
   delay(500);
}
void loop()
{
    if(BlueToothSerial.available())
    {
      Serial.print(char(BlueToothSerial.read()));
    }
    if(Serial.available())
    {
      BlueToothSerial.print(char(Serial.read()));
    }       
}
```

If you use Mega - check serial used by the shield and mopdify the code above.

You did not say which OS runs on your PC Depending on OS you have to select communication method. For Windows if you would like to use COM ports you must pair with arduino first. Then add COM port for the service provided by the shield (it is SPP once).

Once you get the COM number you can use it in your script on PC side and read data from Arduino.

Better way is to communicate with Bluetooth device without COM ports. If you use Windows it can be done with [Bluetooth Framework](http://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm)

Comment: What would I have to add on my Python's script then?

Comment: The code that reads from Bluetooth device. Or leave it as is if your Bluetoth device paired with PC and has vCOM4 created for SPP service